# How to count a column based on repeated values in another column in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, bigdata

I have the following table

| student_id | subjects |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | math |
|  | english |
| 2 | math |

I need to count how many students per subject

I tried doing the following query but had error "exceed resources" on +4TB data (subjects arrays are big in real data)

```
    select subject,count (distinct id)
    from my_table t,
    unnest(t.subjects) subject
    group by subject
```

I think the problem with the unnest and too large data?  any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

try using APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT as in below example

```
select subject, approx_count_distinct(student_id) students
from my_table t,
unnest(t.subjects) subject
group by subject
```